# Missing formula!

Tags: gr.group-theory, characters, algebraic-combinatorics

I am doing a project on group association schemes, in particular looking at the structure constant 
$$p_{KL}^M = \#\{(x, y, xy) : x \in K, y\in L, xy \in M\}$$
where $K, L$ and $M$ are conjugacy classes.

I have been given a formula to help me, but cannot get hold of it anymore! 
It has this expression on the right-hand side: 
$$ \sum_{\chi \in \DeclareMathOperator{\irr}{Irr}
\irr(G)} \frac{\chi(x) \chi(y)}{\chi(xy)}$$
Does anyone recognise this?

Answer (score 4):

There is a well-known formula for these structure constants using character theory. It has a slightly different form to the one you write down (which doesn't look right to me), and you can find it as Exercise (3.9) of Isaacs' *Character Theory of Finite Groups*.

I have an e-version of this book so, if you want a copy, email me. For the record, it's one of my favourite maths books **ever**.